# Is there any possibility to give a alert dialog at the time of open a file in android?

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to give a alert dialog at the time of open a file in android.
I need to ask an alert dialog if the user try to open any file from the SDCard file (or) Phone Gallery files. ???

Comment: you can always if you want to, use the alertbuilder class to build the alert, and depending on the response open or do not open the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to that is using Intents.

Register an intent filter and every time files of a certain description are opened, your application will be given as an option. However, the user must choose your application to get the dialog you want.

See the Android [intents and intent filters guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).